# Using Global Id to specify an object in a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I'm attempting to use global ids to specify polymorphic associations.  However, when I want to reference the object through the association, no object is found.

**Consider the following models:**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :optionees, as: :entity
  belongs_to :company
end
```

and

```
class Optionee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entity, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :option
end
```

**If I seed the above as follows:**

```
Person.create(fname: "John", lname:"Smith", email:"john.smith@email.com", telephone:"555-555-5555", street:"333 Street St", city:"Salt Lake City", state:"UT", zip:"99999", company_id:"1")
```

(Giving the Person an ID of 1)
and

```
Optionee.create total_shares: "332", exercise_price: "33.22" option_id: "1" entity_id: "gid://legal/Person/1"
```

(Giving the Optionee an ID of 1)

I am unable to look up the person with the following command:

```
Optionee.find(1).entity
```

Instead it gives me a nill result.

I realize that the traditional way to do polymorphic associations is to provide the model name AND id; is there somthing I'm missing to do this with global ids?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `entity_type` is missing from optionee.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra thanks for the response.  Indeed entity_type would be necessary if I weren't using a global id.  However the global_id is essentially a uniform resource identifier which should, in principle, allow you to use only one column to signify a polymorphic association.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add entity_type filed in Optionee table as well. And if person id is 1, then entity_id is equals to 1:-

```
Optionee.create total_shares: "332", exercise_price: "33.22" option_id: "1" entity_id: "1", entity_type: "Person"
```

Or you can create record for person in optionee table by doing this:-

```
@person = Person.find(params[:id])
@person.optionees.create(params)
```

It will set entity_id and entity_type for person. By doing this, no need to set entity_id and entity_type explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The point of using a global ID is to consolidate polymorphic associations into one column, as the string is essentially a uniform resource identifier.

Comment: this is a very interesting idea.  Has anyone else used global ID to establish relationships?